# SQL Server 2005 xp_sendmail error

Tags: sql-server, email

I have received this error:

> xp_sendmail: Either there is no default mail client or the current
>   mail client cannot fulfill the
>   messaging request. Please run
>   Microsoft Outlook and set it as the
>   default mail client.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running SQL Server 2005, try to us sp_send_dbmail instead. xp_sendmail is obsolete in SQL Server 2005
For sp_send_dbmail, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

For more on Database Mail, look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

The point is that xp_sendmail might be removed in a future version of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The `xp_sendmail` function requires Outlook to be installed on the SQL Server machine.  When you send an email, it will start Outlook on the server, and use COM to instruct it to send mail.  Like all Office COM interfaces, they sometimes work in a lab environment.  But in production it's guaranteed to fail or crash at the most unlucky time, leaving the server in a permanently farked state.  See this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315886/nl) for more SQL Mail problems.

Try using [`xp_smtp_sendmail`](http://www.nyx.net/~bwunder/SQL2000/15091.htm), or see this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839) for other alternatives.

Comment: It return "Could not find stored procedure 'xp_smtp_sendmail'."

Comment: @bedreddin: That's right, if you follow the link it will tell you how to install it.  Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @bedreddin: Nice, you can [configure SQL 2005 to use SMTP](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/email_functionality_p1.aspx).  Then like Verrigo suggested, sp_send_dbmail will work nicely